# python3 command not found Linux

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-16.04, environment

In my `linux(64 bit, 16.04)` `python3` or `pip` command is not working.
So I tried to find `python3` folder in `/usr/bin`.

And executed

```
cd /usr/bin

cd python3
```

It gave me following error

```
bash: cd: python3: no such file or directory
```

After doing `"ls"` I observed that `python3` folder is in red color

Even `mkdir python3` is throwing error

```
Cannot create directory 'python3' :File exists
```

So is there a way to reinstall `python3` there, Please help.

Comment: Don't try to cd to `/python3`. The slash means to look at the root of the drive. Try `cd python3` instead.

Comment: It gives same error

Comment: Did you try to run it - without slashes - ie. `python3 -V` to check version. OR you can write `python` and press `tab` two times to see if Linux can find it.

Comment: `Ubuntu 16.04` is very old - its number means `2016 April` and it would not have `Python 3` so you may have to install it with `apt-get install python3`

Comment: python3 -V shows -> command not found

Comment: if `apt-get` don't have `python3` then you may try to use unofficial repo with precompiled Pythons for Ubuntu - [deadsnake repo](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Comment: After apt-get install python3 it shows error - "try apt-get -f install" And after executing this command it shows error as-  "Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1)

Comment: maybe you will have to run it as admin/root - `sudo apt-get -f install`. This command can means it had problem in some installation before and now it need to fix (`-f`) some modules.

Comment: It gave same error with sudo as well

Comment: it seems you have to install Ubuntu again. And if you can then install the newest `20.10` or `20.04 LTS` (Long-Term Support) and you will have longer support (and updates)

Comment: if you created folder `python3` then running again `mkdir python3` has to give error. It can't create folder if this folder already exists. Maybe delete this folder.

Comment: BTW: do you have command `python` and `python2` ? I hope you didn't uninstall `python2` because `Ubuntu` needs it to work.

Comment: I think python3 folder is empty hence it is giving errors as no command or directory found . Is there a way to install python libraries again in python3 folder after creating it manually?

Comment: Sorry but python and python2 both shows command not found error

Comment: I think I really have to reinstall ubuntu as you told!

Comment: there shouldn't be folder `/usr/bin/python3` - system keeps Pythons in totally different folders and in `/usr/bin` it keeps only script which runs python.

Comment: python3. 7 command is working, it shows Python3. 7.9(default, Aug18, 2020) and opens python ide

Comment: you could use this `python3.7` but sometimes modules need C/C++ libraries and then you may need `apt-get` to install them.

Comment: Is there a way to make this python3. 7 as default for python3?

Comment: you can always copy `/usr/bin/python3.7` to name `/usr/bin/python3` and you will have `python3` - but first you have to remove folder `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: Ohh I will try that thanks!

Comment: BTW: I wouldn't rename `/usr/bin/python3.7` to `/usr/bin/python3` but I would keep `/usr/bin/python3.7` and create copy with name `/usr/bin/python3` (eventually link `ln -s /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3`)

Comment: Thanks, but it didnt worked either i guess i will just reinstall ubuntu